# How does the tension force of a massless string affect the speed of a mass on its end?

Tags: gravity, energy-conservation, potential-energy, rotation

i,j, and k are the unit vectors in the following question, and $\omega$ is the angular velocity.

Lets say you have a mass m attached to a mass-less string of length $L$ tied to a peg with no friction. Its initial position is $L$ at 90 degrees straight up from the horizontal and it is given an initial velocity $v$ in the positive horizontal direction. I believe this means that it has an initial kinetic energy of:

$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

which is immediately transformed through the tension force into:

$$\frac{1}{2}m \omega ^2 $$

where:

$$\omega = \frac{v}{L}$$

The mass is also influenced by gravity, giving it the potential energy:

$$mgh$$

At a given angle theta from the horizontal, the height from the center is:

$$L\sin(\theta)$$

so the height traversed since it started at the top is:

$$L - L\sin(\theta)$$

Therefore the amount of kinetic energy is added with respect to theta due to gravity is:

$$mg(L-L\sin(\theta)) $$

So the total kinetic energy with respect to theta is:

$$mg(L-L\sin(\theta)) + \frac{1}{2}m \left(\frac{v}{L}\right)^2$$

This gives me the equation, where f is the final velocity:

$$mg(L-L \sin(\theta)) + \frac{1}{2}m\left(\frac{v}{L}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{2}mf^2$$

so:

$$f =\sqrt{\frac{2}{m}\left(mg(L-L\sin(\theta)) + \frac{1}{2}m\left(\frac{v}{L}\right)^2\right)}$$

However, I'm getting strange answers, and something doesn't feel right. What might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Try to use [Math Formatting](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) $a = b+c$ instead of `a = b + c` text formulas.

Comment: $K=\frac{1}{2} m \omega^2$ is incorrect. Check the units. Rotational kinetic energy is $K=\frac{1}{2} I \omega^2$

Comment: So $f = \sqrt{(2(mg(L-L*sin(\theta)) + (1/2)m(\Iota)(v/L)^2)/m)}$
(Don't know why Iota isn't rendering.) Brand new to this forum.

Comment: It is just `I` and not `\Iota` for the mass moment of inertia. I edited the question using math formatting (yw) and now I have to ask where is the tension accounted for in your equations?

Comment: Is the final velocity at the bottom or at the horizontal. The problem is not very well defined as it is.

Comment: And for a point mass, $I=mL^{2}$, so $\frac{1}{2}I\omega^{2}=\frac{1}{2}mL^{2}\left(\frac{v}{L}\right)^{2}=\frac{1}{2}mv^{2}$, which of course is the normal kinetic energy of the particle. It shouldn't be a surprise that the rotational kinetic energy is the same as the translational kinetic energy for a system consisting of a single point particle.

Comment: For a point mass $I=0$ since there are no rotations defined for points.

Comment: If you are talking about rotations about the position of the point, sure. But it certainly has a moment of inertia with regard to rotations about other points, such as the other end of the string it is attached to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total energy at the top is

$$ T = \frac{1}{2} m v^2 + m g L $$

The total energy at some other point is

$$ B = \frac{1}{2} m f^2 + m g L \cos\theta $$

Energy is conserved so

$$ f = \sqrt{v^2 + 2 L g (1-\cos\theta) } $$

Comment: Yeah. I woke up yesterday morning and realized I was way over-complicating a simple problem. Thanks for the answer, that works very well as well!